# Suggestions for our schoolproject android app

Tags: java, android

For our final school project we are making an Android app. We have a function in mind but we don't know how we will achieve it. We have already an user database. What we want to create: if you click a button in our app. it sends a specific gps location to another user. But we don't know how to create this. We hope someone can help us.

Comment: This question is too broad and should be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [this tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/) on how to get location from gps in android. Then there are various ways to send it to another person.

1. If you want to send location only as a text then you can use other apps like facebook messenger, whatsapp, etc. For this You'll need to share the location text via an `Intent`. As follows:

   ```
   String shareBody = "Here is the share content body";
   Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
   sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
   sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject Here");
   sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
   startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, getResources().getString(R.string.share_using)));
   ```
2. If you plan on creating a webservice and send through push notification. Refer [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/).

If you are extremely new to android and don't have knowledge for stuff like setting up a button etc. I suggest you start to read its basics from [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/).